# What are the dimensions for the PSP UMD's game case?

Tags: psp

I'm not talking about the UMD itself, I'm talking about this:

[image]

I tried to search for it but the results I keep getting are those of the UMD disc case and not that one. I don't know what that is called so yeah. Help anyone?

(That picture is not mine, otherwise I would just have measured it myself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cases are 3.89 inches wide by 6.61 inches high with a depth of 0.55 inches (although some may be slightly deeper).

In metric measurements, this is 99mm x 168mm x 14mm.

Answer (score -1):

UMD VIDEO Case dimensions
HxWxD=177x104x14mm